# Couldn't find Post without an ID POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am receiving this error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in MainController#compare Couldn't find
>   Post without an ID

Here is my code for main controller:

```
@job_one = Post.find(params[:j1])
@job_two = Post.find(params[:j2])
```

UPDATE #1:

main_controller.rb

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
def index
   @posts = Post.all.order(id: :asc)
end

def dummy
end

def editor
end

def compare
   @job_one = Post.find(params[:j1])
   @job_two = Post.find(params[:j2])
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.pdf do
       pdf = Prawn::Document.new
       pdf.text "Hello World"
       send_data pdf.render
       end
     end
   end
  end
```

What I am doing is comparing two posts that are made side by side. So these are the two posts I chose from the index page.

Can anyone off some assistance?

Comment: Show your `params`. One of `:j1` and `:j2` is missing. Or both.

Comment: Please add your controller code to the question

Comment: In your error screen you should see a params hash. That should tell you whether the right j1 and j2 parameters are in the request parameters. Another way to see the params hash for a given request, is to watch the server log  (the terminal screen where you are running the server. You might just have a faulty link that brought you there. You can confirm just the controller logic if you append `?j1=3&j2=4` at the end of the url.

Comment: Hey Vincent, I am actually utilizing gem prawn to generate a pdf for a particular section. When I added the ?j1=3&j2=4 at the end of the url it works and a pdf shows. I am wondering how do I fix this cause without the ?j1=3&j2=4 it will give me the same error "Couldn't find Post without an ID POST"

Comment: @IvanWong: yeah, well, according to the code, you **need** both j1 and j2. Right now your pdf seems stubbed, but later on you'll want to add real data to it. Likely using the data from the jobs.